# Importing different classes from a package in java

Tags: java, scala, import, package

I know we can do `import p.*;` to import every class located in package p. But let's say p contains classes A, B and C, and we only want to import A and B, can we do something else than:

```
import p.A;
import p.B;
```

like `import p.{A, B}` in Scala?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no equivalent for Java, you will need to enumerate each class.